# Optimizing K-means algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, k-means

Am trying to follow a paper called [An Optimized Version of K-Means Algorithm](https://fedcsis.org/proceedings/2014/pliks/258.pdf). I have the idea on how K-Means algorithm [works](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/kMean/NumericalExample.htm). That is, grouping the tuples/points into clusters and updating the centroids.

Am trying to implement the method mentioned in the above paper. Their proposed algorithm is this:

[image]

So my doubt is in the second step. I didn't understood what it is being done there! In the paper it says that, we group our data to wider intervals based on the value of `e`, so that later we could avoid iterating through the entire dataset. So, actually how we store it in that `I` (intervals) ? Are we supposed to define a multidimensional array? It's not making sense to me(probably am dumb enough not to get the idea).

The next thing I have doubt is about the step 5. In there, `Cw` is said to be the closest centroid of that point. But how do we figure that out? At first, we would be randomly assigning a point as the centroid. So, are we supposed to loop through the points and find out the `Cw` (the closest centroid) before calculating the `e` ?

The next doubt is on Step 6, which I guess will be able to understand after I get the idea about my previous question regarding Step2.

And the final doubt is regarding Step7. What does it mean by `CjCj'` ? Distance between the previous centroid position to the updated centroid position ?

I have been brain storming about this since the whole day. Any clues would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm revolves around the idea that points which are close to one cluster center and further away from all other cluster centers will stick to that cluster center.  Thus, in subsequent iterations these points don't have to be compared to all cluster centers.

Imagine a point P which has distance 3 to its assigned cluster (i.e. that is the closest distance) and all other clusters are at least 8 or more away. Now, compute the new cluster centers. Let's say that the most any cluster center moved was 2 (that is the value of D in the algorithm, line 7).

You can now be sure that your point still belongs to the same cluster. This is easy to understand if you think about the worst case scenario: The assigned cluster could have moved away from the point so it could be at worst have a new distance of 3+2. The closest other cluster could have moved towards the point so its distance could be now 8-2. Therefore, you don't need to update that point.

Here's a picture:

[image: A sample]

## Your specific questions:

Step 2: Create Intervals into which you later put the points. In step 5 you'll create `e` values. If e is 5, you'd put that point into the interval [4, 6) (if you'd have that interval).

Step 5: Compute the distance of the point to all clusters. The closest cluster is `Cw`. If the next closest cluster is `C3` than `e = C3 - Cw`. I'd call `e` the safety margin. It gives you the maximal distance a cluster can move before assignments might switch.

Step 6: explained with step 2.

Step 7: `CjCj'` is the distance that `Cj` moved when it was updated.

Step 7 & 8: These are done as part of the for loop. (In Step 9 they say "go back to 4").

Step 9: Continue the loop with all points that might have changed clusters.

## More general

This algorithm assumes that you know k-means. I believe this is a very fair assumption. It is not very explicit when to terminate and how to initialise the algorithm. Both of these facts I'd consider common knowledge.

- Initialise the cluster centers by assigning one random point to each. Other initialisation routines exist. The algorithm is not concerned with this part of the algorithm.
- Terminate the algorithm when there are no more intervals which tag is less than 0. This is equivalent to the normal termination criterion in k-means: Stop when no point is assigned to a different cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Got a better understanding from what you have told. But having a hiccup at the worst case scenario that you mentioned.

Comment: I tried to indicate the worst case scenario in my drawing using the circles around C1 and C2. The closest cluster moves away (so it could move at most `D` away) and the next closest cluster (C2 in the image) moves towards the point, thus it could get `D` closer. Thus your "safety margin" `e` can be decreased by `D+D = 2 D`. Clearer?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a clearer idea. Can you please tell what all intervals me we have to make? I guess the intervals it would be: `(0.0,0.1) ; (0.1,0.2) ; (0.3,0.4) ; (0.4,0.5) ; (0.5,0.6) ; (0.6,0.7) ; (0.7,0.8) ; (0.8,0.9) ; (0.9,1.0)`. Am I right? Because I have chosen the `WIDTH` as `0.1`. And am generating the dataset values randomly in between `0` and `1`

Comment: What is your dimensionality? If it is 2, then your maximal euclidean distance value would be `sqrt(2) = 1.4`, thus you need to go up to 1.4 in your last interval. Besides that you would want to pick WIDTH so that you have optimal performance. This depends on your data distribution and there is probably some notes in the paper about this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah, am trying to do 2-dimensional data. In the paper, it says that choosing `WIDTH` plays a significant role. If `WIDTH` is too small, then the number of intervals increase and the workload involved in checking and updating the intervals at each iteration will increase too. But if the `WIDTH` is too big, then the number of points under each interval increases, even though the number of intervals is reduced and there would be performance loss too when a big interval is marked for revisiting! In the paper, the authors picked the `WIDTH` as `0.1` for experimentation.

Comment: You will have to adapt the Intervals to your specific distribution of data. A look at some distance histograms might be useful. Other than that, it's experimentation (you may call it research).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please write a `psuedocode` in simple English (an easier to understand version) so that I could carry out coding the implementation of this algorithm and test it myself?

Comment: First, we could randomly choose 3 points(if my cluster number is 3) from the dataset as the centroids. Then, we could randomly assign all the points to these centroids(clusters) isn't it?

Comment: Or, we should avoid randomly assigning the points to these clusters, instead assign them by calculating the `Euclidean distance`, in the beginning?

Comment: Are those steps 7 & 8, supposed to be done inside the FOR loop? I mean while considering each unvisited points?

Comment: No, I won't write the code for you, not even in pseudocode. I have addressed your other questions in an edit just now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. No I wasn't asking you to code. Just simple steps as I was having the above doubts. Pardon me for asking that. The edits that you made really helped. Sorry for asking doubts again and again. Now my doubt is, in Step6, it says map all points to the Interval matrix based on the `e`. So, we again loop through the points(an inner loop) and do the mapping of each point? Or we just add the current point of which the `e` was calculated to the Interval matrix? I was thinking that we will map only the current point to the Interval!

Comment: And in Step8, it was asked to subtract the `2*D` value from the Interval. So, we only subtract from the single interval in which we mapped the point based on `e`(done in Step6) or we subtract the `2*D` from each of the Interval tags? My guess is that it will be subtracted only from the Interval tag in which that current point has been mapped to. Am I right? Sorry for asking simple questions. Just trying to clear my doubts.

Comment: I have completed implementing a live version in C#. But the problem is the iteration continues. Upon debugging, found that the centroids remain the same position on every iteration. So, I guess something went wrong. http://i.imgur.com/pMUVNnQ.png The first set of centroids is the initial initialization. The later two(the iterations continues infinite) are the updated ones. Which I think has not changed the centroid position at all! Total 20 items in dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Second step: The intervals are on the distance metric, not on coordinates of data.

Fifth step: This is essentially distance to the second closest cluster.

Let me know if you still don't understand the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the replying. But sorry, I still didn't understood it.

Comment: The distance metric means, we are separating the distance matrix ? As per the experimentation that the authors mentioned, they have used the WIDTH as 0.1 and the points that they randomly generated are in between `0` and `1`. So, I did the same. Defined the WIDTH with `0.1`, created `N` number of points in the dataset using the `Random` class. Then set the cluster number to be `3`. And assigned the points in the dataset to random clusters.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether we are supposed to do the Step7 & 8 on considering each point in that FOR loop? Or a simpler `psuedocode` if possible would be highly appreciated. Because am trying to implement a working version of it and test it myself to understand. My understanding is that, we have to repeat this until there is no points in the intervals that has it's tag value less than or equal to `0`

Answer (score 1):

It could be beside the point, if you insist on exactly this algorithm, but the state-of-the-art in K-means is the algorithm described by Ravi Kannan in

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3LQqUQb870

Just wanted to say this in case other people are trying to implement k-means clustering and come to this page. The difficulty in K-means is the initialization.
The paper you are talking about describes a running time optimization, but this optimization does not improve the clustering itself. This algorithm also works only
in 2D.

The state-of-the-art is to run SVD first and do clustering in the principle subspace of dim k. The SVD also gives a nice initialization strategy.

There are other tricks in k-means like thresholding the vectors and so on. The lectures by Ravi Kannan in youtube should give you a hint.

Another simple trick which often works is the so called furthest first traversal.