# More questions on "optimizing K-means algorithm"

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, k-means

I want to implement a paper with "An Optimized Version of the K-Means Clustering Algorithm" title. This paper is in this link : https://fedcsis.org/proceedings/2014/pliks/258.pdf.
This paper is not obvious. I see in stackoverflow that @Vpp Man was ask some question about that ([Optimizing K-means algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044146/optimizing-k-means-algorithm)) but because i have extra question about that, i create new question page.

My questions:

1) Is algorithm2 full of algorithm or I must put it in part of algorithm1 (in step2 of algorithm1)?

2) In step 2 of algorithm2: What is mean of 'i' index? is it iteration number? or is a integer number?

3) In step8 of algorithm2: we must update 'tag' of intervals? we don't should update 'e' of points that are in that intervals too?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Ignore that publication. The authors failed to research the state-of-the-art of modern k-means algorithms, and only read 1970s papers. If you benchmark their "optimized" algorithm against *really optimized* k-means algorithms, it will not perform too well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see code of this algorithm in : https://github.com/cozu/Optimized-K-Means